# In jquery animate, how do I use a custom object instead of a div?

Tags: jquery

My situation started like this: I wanted to animate the background image of a div, but it seems, with jquery I can't retrieve the individual positions of the background images(background-position). So I thought why not create a object and animate it's values then just put this values in the css, but i can't figure out how to quite do it yet. Here's what I tried.

```
var obj={t:0};
                $("#wrapper").animate({
                    obj:100 //I tried obj.t & t as well
                },1000,'linear',function(){},function(){
                    $("#wrapper").css({
                            'background-position':obj.t+"% 0%"
                        });
                });
```

Also another question I need to ask is, if the picture is really big, I mean about 4000x4000px, would it be better to set it as a background image and change the background position, or move around the div itself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the [`step` function](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#step) of the animate method, and more importantly you need to animate the actual object.. not the `#wrapper` element

```
var obj = {
    t: 0
};

$(obj).animate({ // call animate on the object
    t: 100 // specify the t property of the object to be animated
}, {
    duration: 1000,
    easing: 'linear',
    step: function(now) { // called for each animation step (now refers to the value changed)
        $("#wrapper").css({
            'background-position': now + "% 0%"
        });
    }
});
```

**Demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/yPq8s/1/

Comment: step is convenient, and I was doing pretty much the same thing..but step fires for each property being animated right? It would be real troublesome in case of multiple properties, unlike the the current scenario. Any suggestions?

Comment: @aoi, indeed `step` fires for each property animated.. you would need to manually handle the animation for each property... (*`this` refers to your object so you can access all values as they currently are*) [**A simple example**](http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/yPq8s/3/)

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the background position of a background image with the `.css()` method:

```
$('#el').css('background-position');
```

I've created a simple JS Fiddle that animates a background image:

http://jsfiddle.net/yPq8s/

Comment: `background-position-y` (*used in the jsfiddle*) is not standard CSS and is not supported by all browsers..

Comment: What I meant to retrieve was the individual background-position, that is background-position-x, and background-position-y. But that is irrelevant right now, what I am really asking is how can I animate the values of an object

Comment: @aoi The jQuery animate function will only work on properties of an HTML element. What is this object you're trying to animate?

Comment: @StephenYoung, not it will not .. it works with arbitrary objects as well.. as long as the property you try to animate is numeric

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli Oh yes you're right. Sorry for the misinformation. I learnt something new today!

Answer (score 0):

How bout creating a separate div for the background image and if it had content then putting the contents of that div into another div whose z-index is higher and then animating the div(with the background image) itself instead of animating the background-position?

I suppose the answer to your second question is relative to what you are trying to achieve. Though if chose to assign the div with the bg image to its own z-index, then I suppose it d be worth it to play with the div's position itself rather than the background image's background-position.