# background color not working in jquery

Tags: jquery, css, background-color

jquery

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("h2").animate({backgroundColor: '#00f', width: '50%', marginLeft: '50px'});
  });
});
</script>
```

html

```
<h2>This is a heading</h2>
<p style="background: #ff0">This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>
<button>Click me</button>
```

I'm learning jquery and found using css as `margin-left` to `marginLeft` like this in my test `marginLeft` worked but `backgroundColor` could not work. Am I right here or I'm wrong something way?

Answer (score 3):

To animate background color, you need to include a plugin which support it as `jquery UI` or `jquery color`.

http://jsfiddle.net/GW5hB/

Comment: Like said, jquery UI support it or this plugin too, really more lite if you only need it for color animation: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color

Answer (score 0):

It seem's you are not including `jqueryUi.js`

You need this to be included(*after including `jquery.js`*)

```
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js'></script>
```

- http://jqueryui.com/animate/

> jQuery UI bundles the jQuery Color plugins which provides color
>   animations as well as many utility functions for working with colors.

Comment: what are other plugins required for jquery

Answer (score 0):

You will need a plugin that enables animating of background color

from the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/):

> (For example, width, height, or left can be animated but background-color cannot be, unless the jQuery.Color() plugin is used).

Answer (score 0):

Possible workaround to animate colors without jQueryUI, based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10266877/in-jquery-animate-how-do-i-use-a-custom-object-instead-of-a-div#10267038):

```js
function toRGB(hexStr) {
    var s = hexStr.substring(1);
    if (s.length==3) {
        s = s.charAt(0) + s.charAt(0) + s.charAt(1) + s.charAt(1) + s.charAt(2) + s.charAt(2);
    }
    var i = parseInt(s, 16);
    var rcolor = (i & 0xff0000) >> 16;
    var gcolor = (i & 0x00ff00) >> 8;
    var bcolor = i & 0x0000ff;
    return { r:rcolor, g:gcolor, b:bcolor };
}

$('button').click(function(){
    var elem = $('div');
    var c1 = toRGB('#ffffff'), c2 = toRGB('#0000ff');
    $(c1).animate(c2, {
        duration:2000,
        step: function(){
            elem.css('backgroundColor', 'rgb('+parseInt(this.r)+','+parseInt(this.g)+','+parseInt(this.b)+')');
        }
    });

});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lktqk/)